# How dow you start vista in safe mode?

Tags: windows-vista, safe-mode

How do you start Windows Vista in safe mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start tapping your F8 key right after starting your computer.  You'll be prompted with the boot menu which will allow you to select Safe Mode.