# Unable to move or delete files

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, file-management

Just today I got the following error while trying to move/delete several files:

```
The action can't be completed because the file is open in another program.
```

The file wasn't open, but just in case, I closed all programs. When that failed to allow me to move or delete the file, I restarted the computer. When that failed to let me move/delete I came here.

Any suggestions?

The files can be copy/pasted but move/delete fails even after multiple restarts.

### Edit

Note sure if this is relevant, but it seems to only be affecting PSD files on my desktop - there are four. But not ALL PSD files.

Comment: Have you tried "Unlocker"? It's a freeware program

Comment: that can be a VERY dangerous but VERY useful tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe possible that the files are locked/quarantined, in some funky way, by some security software you have installed?

Try deleting the files after booting up in [safe mode](https://superuser.com/questions/102492/how-dow-you-start-vista-in-safe-mode).

If that fails, try deleting them using *[command prompt](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=delete+file+command+prompt+vista)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)** to determine what process has the file open.

Comment: Everyone Needs process Explorer